# How can I allow multiple, optional, and unnamed values in an array in JSON Schema?

Tags: arrays, json, string, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

if this question has already been answered, please let me know. I'm trying to create a JSON Schema file following the specs found on [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/). In general, everything is ok, except for one issue.

I have an array that can contain strings as well as possibly an array of strings. And every string is unnamed, meaning there isn't a key:value pair for it.

I created a [JSON Schema Validator paste](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/IH7trJpk) with the schema I have so far and a sample JSON file I'm using.

However, if you can't check the link above, here's a quick example of what I mean. I have a key called *ArgumentList* which is an array. It contains strings and can optionally contain an array of strings:

```
"ArgumentList": [
 "--profile-directory=Default",
 "--new-window",
 [
   "https://mail.google.com/",
   "https://calendar.google.com/",
   "https://docs.google.com/"
 ]
]
```

For my schema, this is how I'm representing the above:

```
"ArgumentList": {
 "type": "array",
 "items": {
  "type": "string"
 }
}
```

Of course, this schema spec doesn't account for the array of strings. I've tried googling for solutions but I can't figure this out. I've also tried the following:

```
"ArgumentList": {
 "type": "array",
 "items": {
  "type": "string",
  "type": "array"
 }
}
```

But that doesn't work at all. Instead, it resulted in errors in validating my JSON file. Does JSON Schema allow for this type of setup? If so, how do I show that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `anyOf` keyword to assert that your items can be one thing or another. `anyOf` is boolean OR (`||`) operation on schemas.

```json
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "anyOf": [
      { "type": "string" },
      {
        "type": "array",
        "items": { "type": "string" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```